# Is there Sublime Text intellisense for HTML when editing Ruby files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2

I'm enjoying Sublime Text 2 as an editor for my Ruby on Rails project, however, when I'm editing my .erb files, I'm not getting any html help.

For example, if I typed: `<input type="`, I would like to see a list of "text", "button", "file", etc.

I like the Visual Studio intellisense support for HTML, is there something similar for Sublime and Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Maybe your tool does not recognize html file due to erb extension. Have you tried forcing configuration to HTML file ?

Comment: Thanks Nibbler, I manually set the syntax to HTML but still no intellisense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sublime Text has built in intellisense for html, even when editing .erb files. It even does a fuzzy match instead of an exact substring match like most intellisense tools.

1. Ensure your syntax is html (rails). Hit `ctrl+shift+p` and type `Set Syntax: HTML (Rails)`
2. Hit `ctrl+space` whenever you'd like intellisense menu to popup

If you want intellisense to automatically popup instead of hitting `ctrl+space` you can modify the `"auto_complete_triggers"` setting in Preferences.sublime_settings. For example, if you want the intellisense to popup after you've typed `<` or `=` you'd add this to your user settings file:

`"auto_complete_triggers": [ {"selector": "text.html", "characters": "<="} ]`

[image: example of sublime text intellisense]

Comment: Thanks Matt, that will work for sure.  Not as snazzy as a Visual Studio autocomplete, but pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for ctrl+shift+p

Answer (score 0):

In case you want HTML intellisense then follow the below steps
1) CTRL + SHIFT + P -> Install new package
2) Type emmet
3) Install emmet.io
4) Voila you are ready with HTML intellisense in sublime text 2.